# Konva events mis-positioned after screen resize

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

In my code I am resizing the Konva canvas and the konvajs-content elements to maintain a full screen appearance.

```
resizeCanvas()
window.onresize = function() { resizeCanvas(); }

function resizeCanvas() {
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;

    var ratio = x / y;
    var should = 1920 / 1080;

    var cv = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var cc = document.getElementsByClassName("konvajs-content")[0];

    var cx, cy;
    var cleft=0;
    if(ratio > should) {
        cx = (y * 1920/1080);
        cy = y;
        cleft = (x - cx) / 2;
    } else {
        cx = x;
        cy = (x * 1080/1920);
        cv.setAttribute("style", "width:" + x + "px;height:"+ (x*1080/1920) + "px;");
    }
    cc.setAttribute("style", "width:" + x + "px;height: " + y + "px;");
    cv.setAttribute("style", "width:" + cx + "px;heigth: " + cy + "px; position: relative; left: " + cleft + "px");
}
```

This all works great until I try to capture any event input. As you can see in the JSFiddle, when trying to click on the 'Test' text you will not cause an event to fire.

But if you click ~40px to the left and 20px above the text you will fire the events.

https://jsfiddle.net/3qc3wtr3/2/

Is there a way to keep the resize behavior and to ensure that events are being fired based on the actual location of the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `stage.width()` and `stage.height()` to fit a page. You can add scale into stage if you need.